# How to get Artist picture from MPMediaItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaitem, mpmediaitemcollection

I'm searching for a way to get the picture of an Artist through the MediaPlayer library.

I've searched in [the Apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/General_Media_Item_Property_Keys), but there is nothing about that.
The property "Artwork" refers to the album's cover.

Any idea if and how i can get that ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe all that's happening is that an MPMediaItem for music is wrapping the properties of an MP3 tag.  So the artwork is embedded in the source file (.mp3, .aac, etc.

So the question is, where would this Artist's picture come from?  I think you'd have to write your own webservice for this.

I may be wrong however.